# How can I break down query result into separate columns?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Following up from my previous question:

[Pixel values of raster records to be inserted in the table as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13146046/398670)

Imagine my query result has 5300 row as results like:

```
+-------+ 
|value  |
+-------+
| 15624 |
| 15899 |
| 56267 |
| 85955 |
+-------+
```

I want them to be in a table and first 53 rows in `val1` column, second 53 rows in `val2` column and so on. In the end I will have 100 new columns in my table. Is this possible? and if so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I have to ask ... why? I struggle to see how that could serve any useful purpose. In general what you're after is a "pivot" or "crosstab" query (which is annoyingly hard in PostgreSQL) but this is just a _weird_ thing to want. What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve with this, the reason you want to do it?

Comment: Here's how to produce 100 arrays of 530 values each. You can crosstab the result if you really want. `SELECT array_agg(x) from generate_series(1,53000) x GROUP BY width_bucket(x, 1, 53000, 100) ORDER BY 1;` . Of course you'd replace `generate_series` with your table. Note that the values are not ordered within the arrays. If you want ordered arrays you need slower approaches using `array_agg` as a window function.

Comment: I'm sure you saw my previous post on _ Pixel values of raster records (raster files) to be inserted in the table as columns_ there are lots of records and for every record I can extract all the pixel values. Since all the raster files perfectly match one another a pixel withe same rid have the same location as the other raster. I have to put all the corresponding pixel values in one row in a table along with their rid and location.

Comment: From the previous post I couldn't do it, but what I'm able to do is to extract all the pixel values of all the raster files consecutively in a query. this is the reason to post this question. I hope I could convey the message.

Comment: I was wrong above, you don't need to use array_agg as a window function, you just specify order of aggregation. This is fast. `SELECT array_agg(x order by x) from generate_series(1,53000) x GROUP BY width_bucket(x, 1, 53000, 100) ORDER BY 1;`. That gives you the result you want, just row-oriented instead of column-oriented. Converting it to columns is (a) a pretty bad idea since PostgreSQL is limited to 250-1600 columns per row anyway (http://www.postgresql.org/about/) and (b) going to require a verbose and annoying crostab query if it works at all.

Comment: Thank you. I got a result like `{38161,38162,38163,38164,38165,38166,38167,38168,38169,38170,38171,38172 . . .}` but is it retrievable? I mean if I want to know the nth number in this series, what should I do?

Comment: It's an array. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html . Index arrays with the `[]` operator eg `[32]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [possibly somewhat saner approach using multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13150376/398670).

Please never, ever, ever, ever use the following query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT ''row1''::text, width_bucket(x, 1, 53001, 100), array_agg(x order by x)::integer[] from generate_series(1,53000) x GROUP BY 2'
) ct(
 rowname text,
    col1 integer[], col2 integer[], col3 integer[], col4 integer[], col5
    integer[], col6 integer[], col7 integer[], col8 integer[], col9 integer[],
    col10 integer[], col11 integer[], col12 integer[], col13 integer[], col14
    integer[], col15 integer[], col16 integer[], col17 integer[], col18 integer[],
    col19 integer[], col20 integer[], col21 integer[], col22 integer[], col23
    integer[], col24 integer[], col25 integer[], col26 integer[], col27 integer[],
    col28 integer[], col29 integer[], col30 integer[], col31 integer[], col32
    integer[], col33 integer[], col34 integer[], col35 integer[], col36 integer[],
    col37 integer[], col38 integer[], col39 integer[], col40 integer[], col41
    integer[], col42 integer[], col43 integer[], col44 integer[], col45 integer[],
    col46 integer[], col47 integer[], col48 integer[], col49 integer[], col50
    integer[], col51 integer[], col52 integer[], col53 integer[], col54 integer[],
    col55 integer[], col56 integer[], col57 integer[], col58 integer[], col59
    integer[], col60 integer[], col61 integer[], col62 integer[], col63 integer[],
    col64 integer[], col65 integer[], col66 integer[], col67 integer[], col68
    integer[], col69 integer[], col70 integer[], col71 integer[], col72 integer[],
    col73 integer[], col74 integer[], col75 integer[], col76 integer[], col77
    integer[], col78 integer[], col79 integer[], col80 integer[], col81 integer[],
    col82 integer[], col83 integer[], col84 integer[], col85 integer[], col86
    integer[], col87 integer[], col88 integer[], col89 integer[], col90 integer[],
    col91 integer[], col92 integer[], col93 integer[], col94 integer[], col95
    integer[], col96 integer[], col97 integer[], col98 integer[], col99 integer[],
    col100 integer[]
);
```

The correct way to solve this problem is almost certainly *in your application*. SQL is good at many things. This isn't one of them, especially in PostgreSQL with its very limited pivot support. In any database this would be a crazy thing to do.

As far as I'm concerned, if I have to use a query just to generate the column-list, that's a sign the system is being forced to do something it isn't well suited for:

```
select string_agg('col'||n||' integer[]',', ') FROM generate_series(1,100) n;
```

Comment: I'm tempted to use! Thank you

Comment: @f.ashouri I've just corrected an error in the query; I should've used 100 width_buckets with range 1-53001

Comment: @f.ashouri: Be strong; resist the temptation!