# Repeat a column, duplicating it into more identical columns in the same row

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have table with 3 columns like this: `(ID, city,city_pop).` I just want copy **city_pop** column 20 times. So the final table will look like something this: `(ID, city, city_pop, city_pop1, city_pop2, ...city_pop20)` with same values as **city_pop** has. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- CREATE TABLE cities20 AS
SELECT id,city
    , city_pop AS city_pop0
    , city_pop AS city_pop1
    , city_pop AS city_pop2
    , city_pop AS city_pop3
    , city_pop AS city_pop4
    , city_pop AS city_pop5
    , city_pop AS city_pop6
    , city_pop AS city_pop7
    , city_pop AS city_pop8
    , city_pop AS city_pop9
    , city_pop AS city_pop10
    , city_pop AS city_pop11
    , city_pop AS city_pop12
    , city_pop AS city_pop13
    , city_pop AS city_pop14
    , city_pop AS city_pop15
    , city_pop AS city_pop16
    , city_pop AS city_pop17
    , city_pop AS city_pop18
    , city_pop AS city_pop19
 FROM cities
     ;
```

Comment: Gah. I was too stuck in the frame of mind of the poster's previous pivot table questions to see the obvious. Thankyou.

Comment: *simplicity is my sole virtue ;-)*

Answer (score 2):

This is another job for [`crosstab` from the `tablefunc` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), though [again it seems like a truly bizarre thing to want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149878/398670).

Setup of demo data and to load the `tablefunc` extension:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (ID integer, city text, city_pop integer);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES (1,'Boganville',200), (2, 'Amity', 543);

CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Query:

```
SELECT city, ct.* FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT id, ''city_pop''||CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN '''' ELSE x::text END AS colname, city_pop  FROM generate_series(1,20) x CROSS JOIN cities ORDER BY 1, x;'
) ct(
    cityid integer,
    city_pop integer, city_pop2 integer, city_pop3 integer, city_pop4 integer,
    city_pop5 integer, city_pop6 integer, city_pop7 integer, city_pop8 integer,
    city_pop9 integer, city_pop10 integer, city_pop11 integer, city_pop12 integer,
    city_pop13 integer, city_pop14 integer, city_pop15 integer, city_pop16 integer,
    city_pop17 integer, city_pop18 integer, city_pop19 integer, city_pop20 integer
) INNER JOIN cities ON (ct.cityid = cities.id);
```

Result:

```
    city    | cityid | city_pop | city_pop2 | city_pop3 | city_pop4 | city_pop5 | city_pop6 | city_pop7 | city_pop8 | city_pop9 | city_pop10 | city_pop11 | city_pop12 | city_pop13 | city_pop14 | city_pop15 | city_pop16 | city_pop17 | city_pop18 | city_pop19 | city_pop20 
------------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 Boganville |      1 |      200 |       200 |       200 |       200 |       200 |       200 |       200 |       200 |       200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200 |        200
 Amity      |      2 |      543 |       543 |       543 |       543 |       543 |       543 |       543 |       543 |       543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543 |        543
(2 rows)
```

Col list generated with:

```
SELECT string_agg( 'city_pop'||CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN '' ELSE x::text END || ' integer', ', ')  FROM generate_series(1,20) x;
```

Comment: I imagine the first 2 lines are not needed if my table already existed and has lots of data. Am I right?

Comment: @f.ashouri Er, yes. They're setup so that the query can actually run, demonstrating that it works.

Comment: did you do it in pgsql? I ran your exact code and I got this error: **ERROR:  function crosstab(unknown) does not exist
LINE 5: SELECT city, ct.* FROM crosstab(
                               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

Comment: @f.ashouri I presumed you'd been following along from our previous discussion and understood that the `crosstab` function is provided by the `tablefunc` extension. Answer updated.

Comment: Actually I am not superuser and I don't have permission to create an extension. So, I did a silly mistake and I imagined this is not needed. I tested it in local account and it is working. Thank you

Comment: And I wanted the result to be in the table actually

Comment: @f.ashouri Well, it can't go into *the* table, because it has a different structure. To put it into a *new* table, use `SELECT ... INTO`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: @CraigRinger `CREATE TABLE AS ...` >> `SELECT ... INTO`. I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-selectinto.html): `The PostgreSQL usage of SELECT INTO to represent table creation is historical. It is best to use CREATE TABLE AS for this purpose in new code.`

Comment: Also, I think you over-interpreted this question. No use for `crosstab()`here.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I *certainly* over-interpreted the question; the user had several prior pivot/crosstab questions, so I was too much in that frame of mind. As for `SELECT ... INTO` - I didn't realise that was a PostgreSQLism, so thankyou. I'll purge it from my vocab.